# Using Erlang, how can a "timestamp", in POSIX time, be derived from a Gregorian date and time?

Tags: nmea, gtfs

I'm writing a program that receives data in the form of GPRMC NMEA sentences and outputs it as specified by GTFS-realtime.

GTFS-realtime wants a "timestamp" value, and describes it as such:

> Moment at which the vehicle's position was measured. In POSIX time (i.e., number of seconds since January 1st 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Here's a complete GPRMC sentence, with the relevant fields bolded:

`$GPRMC,`**123519**`,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,`**230394**`,003.1,W*6A`

The above tells me that the reading was taken at `12:35:19` on `23/03/94`.

According to http://www.epochconverter.com/, this date and time is represented as `767104519` in POSIX time.

Using Erlang, what is the best way to go about deriving a POSIX timestamp from a GPRMC NMEA sentence?